# Commit values in SyntaxErrorMessageProvider and use them in QuickfixProvider?

Tags: java, xtext, xtend

I am overriding the standard error messages used by Xtext. In my `SyntaxErrorMessageProvider` I am checking feature types. If the user typed in an `double` there should be a possibility to change it to `integer` by simply cutting the decimal places.

```
@Override
public SyntaxErrorMessage getSyntaxErrorMessage(IParserErrorContext context) {
    if (context.getRecognitionException() instanceof MismatchedTokenException) {
        MismatchedTokenException exception = (MismatchedTokenException) context
                .getRecognitionException();
        String value = exception.token.getText();
        if (isDouble(value)) {
            return new SyntaxErrorMessage("Parser error: The parameter '"
                    + value + "' has a wrong type. It should be integer.",
                    IssueCodes.UNEXPECTED_DOUBLE_VALUE);
        }
    }
    // should never happen!
    return null;
}
```

The new `SyntaxErrorMessage` object only holds the error message and the `IssueCode`. In my `QuickfixProvider` I want to offer a quickfix, which changes the `DOUBLE` value to an `INTEGER`:

```
@Fix(IssueCodes.UNEXPECTED_DOUBLE_VALUE)
public void changeDoubleToInt(final Issue issue,
        IssueResolutionAcceptor acceptor) {
    acceptor.accept(issue, "Change to integer", "Change variable value to integer.",
            "correction_change.gif", new IModification() {
                public void apply(IModificationContext context)
                        throws BadLocationException {
                    IXtextDocument xtextDocument = context
                            .getXtextDocument();
                    // cut decimal places
                }
            });
}
```

But to do that, I need the `double` value. Is it possible to commit the double value in the `SyntacErrorMessageProvider` so that I can work with it in the `QuickfixProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

`SyntaxErrorMessage` has a second constructor with an additional array `String[] issueData`. You can use this to pass additional data. It should be possible to get this data using `issue.getData()` in the quickfix provider.